# Passing Parameters to a jQuery 'Load'

Tags: jquery

I have some script on my page which is:

```
$('#divMenuHolder').load('../menu.html');
```

However I also need to be able to pass some parameters which are acted on the menu.html page.

I've tried the following:

```
$('#divMenuHolder').load('../menu.html?opt1=test&opt2=test2');
```

However when I come to get the parameters using the following function:

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

It returns nothing because it's trying to get the parameters of the page itself, and not the page I'm loading into DIV.

Can anyway assist in guiding me to what I want please?

Comment: Why do you want to get the parameters from the div in the first place? You put them in there yourself (when calling `load`), so you already know their values.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

```
$('#semester').load("restricted/getSemester.php?courseid=" + $("#course").val());
```

where `#course` is id of input field.

OR

```
$('#subject').load("restricted/getSubject.php?courseid=0&semester=0");
```

I hope this helps u :)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this jQuery load() documentation example](http://api.jquery.com/load/#example-3):

> Example: pass arrays of data to the
>   server.
>
> ```
> $("#objectID").load("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] } );
> ```

Function definition:

> `.load( url, [data,] [complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )`
>
> `url` A string containing the URL to
>   which the request is sent.
>
> **`data` A map or string that is sent to
>   the server with the request.**
>
> `complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)`
>   A callback function
>   that is executed when the request
>   completes.

Comment: Thanks Kon, have looked at that but getting a "405 Method Not Allowed" error message, everything is on the same domain so will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
var url_to_load = '../menu.html?opt1=test&opt2=test2';
$('#divMenuHolder').load(url_to_load);

function getUrlVars(url_to_load)
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = url_to_load.slice(url_to_load.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to a similar problem. Was Just wondering if you have found the solution. I found a workaround but its not suitable for my application.

One of the options is to set the cookie before you load the URl and access the cookie in the seperate html page. But cookies can be disabled so you have to be careful on that part.Also if your separate html is going to reusable , then you need to figure out the perfect solution , cookies are not useful in that case.

Comment: var qs = (function(a) { if (a == "") return  {}; var b = {}; for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) { var p=a[i].split('='); if (p.length != 2) continue; b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")); } return b; })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));