# $_REQUEST['id'] from page inside a php file called by a javascript to another php page

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get the value **3** from this link: `index.php?subtopic=example&id=3`
Normally I would use the $_REQUEST['id'] but I'm facing another situation here.

I got the example1.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chatbox.js"></script>
...
<div id="chat_box"></div>
```

And then the chatbox.js:

```
setInterval( function() {
$('#chat_box').load('chatbox.php');
} , 100 );
```

And finally the chatbox.php:

```
echo $_REQUEST['id'];
```

but I can't get the id value here :/  Please Help!!!

Comment: Where is include the chatbox.php?

Comment: the chatbox.php is included in chatbox.js: ".load('chatbox.php')"
I'm trying to print this result on the div at exemple1.php to show just messages from the contact with id 3

Comment: You need pass the value in load function. `load('chatbox.php?id=1')`

Comment: I hope that this link help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410457/passing-parameters-to-a-jquery-load

Comment: sorry I did it wrong, I used the & instead of ? now it's working but how I'll make the file chatbox.js load the value 3?

Comment: I solved that, how can I post here how I did that to other people see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to parse the id out of the URL and send it to the chat - let's do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getID() {
    var tmp=location.href.split('?');
    if (tmp.length!=2) return -2;
    tmp=tmp[1].split('&');
    for (i=0;i<tmp.length;i++) {
      var param=tmp[i].split('=');
      if (param.length!=2) continue;
      if (param[0]!="id") continue;
      return parseInt(param[1]);
    }
    return -3;
  }

  var chaturl='chatbox.php?id='+getID();

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chatbox.js"></script>
...
<div id="chat_box"></div>
```

...

```
setInterval( function() {
$('#chat_box').load(chaturl);
} , 100 );
```

Comment: I'm getting a result like ( -3 )

Comment: Ah! There was a typo! Instead of `tmp.length` I had `tmp.lenght`, please retry.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it here:

example1.php

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
setInterval( function() {
$('#chat_box').load('chatbox.php?id=".$_GET['id']."');
} , 100 );
</script>";

echo '<div id="chat_box"></div>';
```

and chatbox.php:

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: You really should sanitize the input! Someone sending an id parameter of `3&foo=bar&baz=something` is able to inject each and any GET parameter into your chatbox.

Comment: but there's a script on page like this:`if(in_array($_GET['id'],explode(",",$acc_logged->getfriendslist()))){ page content }else{$error[] = 'you dont have friends with this id.....';}`

but thanks anyway!